# minimizing $\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)-k)^2dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, maxima-minima

For which values of $k$ , does $ \int_{a}^{b}(f(x)-k)^2 dx\,$ take the minimum ?
one of my friends asked me this today and I don't even know am I supposed to find a certain real number $k$ or $k$ is a function of $a$ and $b$ or even $f$ itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to observe that
$$
\begin{split}
\int_a^b(f(x)-k)^2 dx & = \int_a^b (k^2 - 2k f(x) + f(x)^2)\, dx
\\ & = (b-a) k^2 - 2 \left(\int_a^b f(x)\, dx\right) k + \int_a^b f(x)^2\, dx
\end{split}
$$
is a second order polynomial in $k$, which is minimized when
$$
k = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)\, dx.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$k$ is simply the average of $f$ over the region of integration.  To see this, you can differentiate inside the integral (given that the integral exists, etc.):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k} \int_a^b dx \, (f(x)-k)^2 = -2 \int_a^b dx \, (f(x)-k) = 0$$

Accordingly,

$$(b-a) k = \int_a^b dx \, f(x)$$

and my assertion above follows.